# Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined while using plotly in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, plotly

I was trying to use plotly graph library in Angular 6, the graph plotting is working fine but unable to identify how to use plotly JavaScript APIs using the angular component(https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/blob/master/README.md ).

So, I'm using following code in angular component to directly access plotly JavaScript APIs like deleteTrace, addTrace..

```
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js';
```

But while accessing the Plotly object I'm getting this error:

```
index.js:6 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/has-hover/index.js (index.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/plotly.js/src/plot_api/plot_api.js (plot_api.js:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/plotly.js/src/plot_api/index.js (index.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/plotly.js/src/core.js (core.js:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
    at Object../node_modules/plotly.js/lib/core.js (core.js:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:76)
```

Comment: why do you import as this? this is not necessary i think.

Comment: I want to use: Plotly.plot(document.getElementById("anomaly-plot"), this.graph.data, this.graph.layout);

Comment: @Asanka, can you please suggest some examples how I can use Plotly APIs using angular component.

Comment: why you don't use it's in angular way? please tell me what you exactly want to do?

Comment: I mean in GitHub documentation there is not importing plot.js like this.

Comment: Initially I'm setting the layout of the graph, once I'm getting the data from server I'm pushing those records into data and the graph displaying those options but all the layout properties are not working anymore. I'm not getting many examples how to draw the plot once all my data is loaded by angular, so I was trying to do by using the JavaScript API using a div element.

Comment: can  you demostrate your code in stackblitz i can help you.

Comment: Do you familiar with viewChild? that might be useful.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181626/discussion-between-roul-and-asanka).

Comment: I figured out the solution, instead of Plotly directly I had to use "window.Plotly"

Answer (score 2):

Add `(window as any).global = window;` in your polyfills.ts file. This should work in Chrome, Firefox and Edge. Not sure about IE browser.